# Is there anyway to extend this select function?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, redis

```py
def __select__(self, line,code="CER400"):
   line = self.validationData["line"]
   def process_sql_query(sql_query, json_data):
       table_name = sql_query[3]

       # Get the WHERE clause from the SQL query
       where_clause = sql_query[next((i for i, item in enumerate(sql_query) if item.upper() == 'WHERE'), -1)+1:] if any(item.upper() == 'WHERE' for item in sql_query) else []
       # Convert the JSON data to a Python dictionary
       data = json.loads(json_data)[table_name]['data']
       # Initialize a list to store the result values
       result_values = []

       # Check if WHERE clause exists
       if where_clause and len(where_clause) >= 3:
           # Split the WHERE clause into individual parts
           conditions = []
           logical_operator = None

           for item in where_clause:
               if item.upper() in ['AND', 'OR']:
                   logical_operator = item.upper()
               else:
                   conditions.append(item)

           # Initialize a set to store the temporary results
           temp_results = set()

           for i in range(0, len(conditions), 3):
               field_to_compare = conditions[i]
               operator = conditions[i+1]
               value_to_compare = conditions[i+2]

               # Iterate over the keys in the data dictionary
               for key, json_object in data.items():
                   # Check if the field value matches the condition in the WHERE clause
                   if operator == '=' and str(json_object.get(field_to_compare)) == value_to_compare:
                       temp_results.add(key)
                   elif operator == '!=' and str(json_object.get(field_to_compare)) != value_to_compare:
                       temp_results.add(key)
                   elif operator == '>' and int(json_object.get(field_to_compare, 0)) > int(value_to_compare):
                       temp_results.add(key)
                   elif operator == '<' and int(json_object.get(field_to_compare, 0)) < int(value_to_compare):
                       temp_results.add(key)
                   elif operator == '>=' and int(json_object.get(field_to_compare, 0)) >= int(value_to_compare):
                       temp_results.add(key)
                   elif operator == '<=' and int(json_object.get(field_to_compare, 0)) <= int(value_to_compare):
                       temp_results.add(key)
                   elif operator.upper() == 'LIKE' and re.search(value_to_compare, str(json_object.get(field_to_compare, ''))):
                       temp_results.add(key)

           if logical_operator == 'AND':
               # Filter the results using all the conditions
               self.temp_results = data.keys()
               result_values = [data[key] for key in temp_results if all(check_condition(key) for check_condition in get_condition_functions(conditions, data))]
           elif logical_operator == 'OR':
               # Add the results that satisfy any of the conditions
               self.temp_results = data.keys()
               result_values = [data[key] for key in temp_results] + [data[key] for key in data.keys() if key not in temp_results and any(check_condition(key) for check_condition in get_condition_functions(conditions, data))]
           else:
             self.temp_results = data.keys()
             result_values = [data[key] for key in temp_results] + [data[key] for key in data.keys() if key not in temp_results and any(check_condition(key) for check_condition in get_condition_functions(conditions, data))]

       else:
           # Return all objects since there is no WHERE clause
           self.temp_results = data.keys()
           result_values = list(data.values())

       return filterBy(filter_by_header(result_values , self.validationData['line'][1]))
   def filterBy(data):
     if "distinct" in self.validationData["filters"].keys():
       """Get a List unique dictionaries
       List to contain unique dictionaries"""
       listofDicts = data
       listOfUniqueDicts = []
   
       # A set object
       setOfValues = set()
   
       # iterate over all dictionaries in list
       for dictObj in listofDicts:
           list_Of_tuples = []
           # For each dictionary, iterate over all key
           # and append that to a list as tuples
           for key, value in dictObj.items():
               list_Of_tuples.append( (key, value))
   
           strValue = ""
           # convert list of tuples to a string
           for key, value in sorted(list_Of_tuples):
               # sort list of tuples, and iterate over them
               # append each pair to string
               strValue += str(key) + "_" + str(value) + "_"
   
           # Add string to set if not already exist in set
           if strValue not in setOfValues:
               # If string is not in set, then it means
               # this dictionary is unique
               setOfValues.add(strValue)
               listOfUniqueDicts.append (dictObj)
               
       data = listOfUniqueDicts
     
     if "asc" in self.validationData["filters"]:
       sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: int(x['id']))
       data = sorted_data
     
     if "dsc" in self.validationData["filters"]:
       sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: int(x['id']), reverse=True)
       data = sorted_data
     
     if "orderBy" in self.validationData["filters"].keys():
       field = self.validationData["filters"]["orderBy"]["field"]
       order = self.validationData["filters"]["orderBy"]["how"]
       print(field , order)
       sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[field], reverse=(order == 'dsc'))
       data = sorted_data
     return data
   def filter_by_header(data, keys):
     if(keys == "*"):
       return data
     else:
       keys = keys.split(',')
       result = []
       for item in data:
           new_dict = {}
           for key in keys:
               if key in item:
                   new_dict[key] = item[key]
           result.append(new_dict)
       return result
   def get_condition_functions(conditions, data):
       """
       Helper function to generate condition functions based on the conditions provided.
       Each condition function checks if a given key satisfies the corresponding condition.
       """
       condition_functions = []
       for i in range(0, len(conditions), 3):
           field_to_compare = conditions[i]
           operator = conditions[i+1]
           value_to_compare = conditions[i+2]
           condition_functions.append(create_condition_function(field_to_compare, operator, value_to_compare, data))
       return condition_functions
   def create_condition_function(field, operator, value, data):
       """
       Helper function to create a condition function based on the field, operator, and value.
       """
       if operator == '=':
           return lambda key: str(data[key].get(field)) == value
       elif operator == '>':
           return lambda key: int(data[key].get(field, 0)) > int(value)
       elif operator == '<':
           return lambda key: int(data[key].get(field, 0)) < int(value)
       elif operator == '>=':
           return lambda key: int(data[key].get(field, 0)) >= int(value)
       elif operator == '<=':
           return lambda key: int(data[key].get(field, 0)) <= int(value)
       elif operator.upper() == 'LIKE':
           pattern = value.replace('%', '.*')
           regex = re.compile(pattern, re.IGNORECASE)
           return lambda key: regex.search(str(data[key].get(field, ''))) is not None
       else:
           return lambda key: False
           
   table_name = self.validationData['table_name']
   table = self.redisConn.get(table_name)
   if(self.__validateTable__(table,table_name,False) == False):
     return
   allData = table.decode()  # Decode the byte string to a regular string
   result = process_sql_query(line, allData)
   if(code == "CER200"):
     return result
   ResultView(result).display()
```

The provided code is a part of a larger codebase. It seems to define a class or a function named `__select__`, which takes three parameters: `self`, `line`, and `code`.

1. The `__select__` function starts by assigning the value of `self.validationData["line"]` to the `line` variable, but this assignment seems redundant since `line` is already a parameter.
2. The function defines a nested function called `process_sql_query`, which appears to process a SQL query and perform filtering on a JSON data object based on the query's conditions. The filtered result is then passed through the `filterBy` function, which applies additional filtering and sorting based on the `self.validationData['filters']` criteria.
3. The `filterBy` function performs several operations on the input data. Here's a summary of what each part does:

   - If the 'distinct' key is present in `self.validationData['filters']`, it filters the data to keep only unique dictionaries based on a selected set of keys.
   - If the 'asc' key is present, it sorts the data in ascending order based on the 'id' field.
   - If the 'dsc' key is present, it sorts the data in descending order based on the 'id' field.
   - If the 'orderBy' key is present, it sorts the data based on the specified field and order ('asc' or 'dsc').
4. The `filter_by_header` function filters the data to include only the specified keys from each dictionary.
5. The `get_condition_functions` function generates a list of condition functions based on the conditions provided in the SQL query. These condition functions are used to check if a given key satisfies the corresponding condition.
6. The `create_condition_function` function creates a condition function based on the field, operator, and value. The specific condition functions check if a given key satisfies the condition for a particular field.
7. The code then proceeds to obtain the `table_name` and retrieve the corresponding table data from a Redis database using `self.redisConn.get()`. It performs some table validation and then calls the `process_sql_query` function with the `line` and `allData` as arguments. The resulting filtered and sorted data is returned or displayed depending on the value of `code`.

It's important to note that this code snippet lacks some necessary context, such as the class or function declaration that encapsulates it, as well as the specific purpose and expected behavior of the code. Providing additional details would help in giving a more accurate and comprehensive explanation.

This was short description of the code

I want now to support parentheses for the process_sql_query note the select cmd is splitted before it goes into select function

Can any one please helps me?

Comment: It looks like `sql_query()` is already a parsed query, since it's a list, not a string. For instance, the table name is in `sql_query[3]`. Supporting parentheses will require changing the code that creates or parses the query before calling this.

Comment: Writing a parser for complex expressions is non-trivial, and more than you can expect from a SO answer.

Comment: Barmer - I know it is very complex but i have got an idea from you thanks.